# How to make two Coins toss probabilities change simultaneously?

Tags: probability, statistics

**Hello , I am trying to make a coin toss game where the probabilities decrase by 1/2 everytime the same face of the coin appears and in the same time increases by that amount for the other face**

exemple:

```
heads 0 - tails 0 ---> Probabilities : 50% 50% 
heads 1 - tails 0 ---> Probabilities : 25% 75% 
heads 2 - tails 0 ---> Probabilities : 12.5% 87.5% 
heads 2 - tails 1 ---> Probabilities : 25% 75%
heads 2 - tails 2 ---> Probabilities : 50% 50%
heads 2 - tails 3 ---> Probabilities : 75% 25%
etc...
```

To make this happen I made two variable , headtimes(how many times heads appeared) and tailtimes(how many times appeared) , and I used the following formula to get the percentage of each (the initial chances are 50% 50%):

```
headstats = 50/2^(headtimes-tailtimes) 
tailstats = 100-headstats
```

But it is not functional , as the probabilities jump directly to 100 if the first toss is tails  50/2^(0-1)

Sorry for my bad english epression and thank you already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get what you're saying correctly I guess what you need is the following:(H,T are Headtimes and Tailtimes respectively)
$Headstats=( \frac{1}{2}-sgn(H-T)*(\frac{1}{2}-2^{-|H-T|-1}))*100$
$Tailstats=100-Headstats$

Comment: Oh thank you , I had figured it out , so I deleted my comments just before you comment !!! anyway , thanks a looooooooooooooooooooooooooot , it's perfect , I am so thankful !

Comment: I am a very young student and I would love to know what branch of mathematics to study to be able to solve such things ? any suggestion ?

Comment: This is not a professional advice but I think Computer Science is the closest major to this

Comment: Thank you infinitely sir , I will take by your advice !

Comment: You're welcome ;)

Answer (score 1):

WLOG the number of **turns** that have already occurred that have been recorded as Heads (= H) is greater than or equal to the number of turns that have already occurred that have been recorded as Tails (= T).

Then, you want that the chance of a Heads being recorded on the next turn to be  $\frac{1}{2^{(H+1-T)}}.$

Clearly you will want the chance of a Tails being recorded on the next turn to be 1 - (the chance of a Heads being recorded on the next turn).

The easiest way to do that is to re-define a **turn** as follows:
Assuming that $(H + 1 - T) \geq 1,$ a Heads will be registered for the turn if and only if, on this turn, when a coin is tossed (H + 1 - T) times, it comes up heads each time.

If so, the H(eads) is recorded for this turn.  If not, a T(ails) is recorded for this turn.

Then, you move on to the next turn.

**Addendum**
Responding to the OP's comment:

> ...but I have to do it with only one formula , not an algorithm

Unclear what you intend here.  I'll take a stab at it.  Let me know if I have misinterpreted your comment.

Assume that the number of **turns** $=N$ is a known value.

Assume that the number of Heads ($H$'s) that have been recorded on these $N$ turns is also a known value.

You can eliminate any consideration of which turns have been recorded as Tails in the following manner:

- On a given turn, compute $D = (2H - N)$ and flip a coin $|D| + 1$ times.
- If $D \geq 0$ record Heads on the turn **only if all** $|D| + 1$ coin flips come up heads.
- If $D < 0$ record Heads on the turn if **any** of the
  $|D| + 1$ coin flips come up heads.

Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: It seems correct , but I have to do it with only one formula , not an algorithm

Comment: Thanks a lot sir

Comment: @Salamand See the Addendum just added to my answer, and let me know if this is what you were looking for.